# Evernote invalid token

Tags: evernote

I was making a small app for myself. Basically it will move all notes under specific folder of one account (yinxiang.com account) to another folder of another account (international account). Based on the sample code from Evernote.com, part of the code looks something like this:

```
source_auth_token = "xxx"
source_client = EvernoteClient(token = source_auth_token, sandbox=False)
source_note_store = source_client.get_note_store()
source_notebooks = source_note_store.listNotebooks()
```

I have two developer tokens, one from my yinxiang.com account, and the other from the international account. The one from the international account works just fine, but the other one from yinxiang.com doesn't. It keeps telling me:

```
evernote.edam.error.ttypes.EDAMSystemException: EDAMSystemException(errorCode=8, _message='authenticationToken')
```

Notice that I have changed `sandbox=True` to `sandbox=False`, and I have revoked the developer tokens from both accounts several time. And again, my international account works just fine. It seems to me that there's **something wrong with the token from my yinxiang.com account**. Even if I tried running **EDAMTest.py** from the sample folder with the **yinxiang** token, it doesn't work.

Is it because of the server of yinxiang.com or just something else?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not requesting the "international" noteStore with the yinxiang token ?
Maybe you can provide more code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for yinxiang:

```
client = EvernoteClient(token=yinxiang_token, service_host="app.yinxiang.com")
```